# Can you hide the URL for a Slack preview?

Tags: slack

Is there a way to  hide the URL for a Slack web preview? See below, the URL is quite long -

[image: example of a web preview’s URL]

Can you disable this URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible to remove a URL from a slack web preview.

If the URL's are taking up too much space perhaps a [URL shortener](https://bitly.com/) could be helpful.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is correct. Thank you for the url shortener Idea, this is great. I will be passing this along to Slack, let’s hope we can find some help here